# How to make Postgres start automatically on boot

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Ubuntu and I would like to know how to make postgresql start automatically on boot and how to configure my setup so that I can start the postgres server if need be.

I am working on a small rails project and I have been having difficulties with postgres starting correctly. I have had to resort to uninstalling and reinstalling postgres to just get the project up and running just to get work done. I have been using these commands.

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get purge postgresql* # ending * is important
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

from this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934055/postgresql-cannot-connect-to-server-locally

skipping

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
```

as it appears it is out of date and there's a comment below about not needing it.

If it helps my pg_hba.conf file appears to be located at

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on top of chrome os

Thanks all for the help and sorry for the newb question!

Comment: Why are you using some random person's PPI? Use http://apt.postgresql.org/ if you want current PostgreSQL releases on older platforms.

Comment: Craig thanks for the response. Just to clarify the what would the command be to pull from the apt.postgresql.org be?

Comment: @cwmacken there are instructions in the linked page (including commands).

Comment: @Craig haha sorry missed that it was a link. Thanks for the help! Cheers

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to start postgres on startup so that you wont have to restart is all the time simply do:

```
sudo update-rc.d postgresql enable
```

this will always start your postgres on boot startup.
hope it helps someone

Comment: I get error:
`update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for postgrsql`
But I installed postgresql from other repo (http://1c.postgrespro.ru/deb/) because it has special patches I need.

Comment: Thank you! My problem was: I disabled the service with `systemctl disable postgresql.service`. But I was no longer able to enable it with `systemctl`. Your answer was the solution. My system: Debian 8.8 x64 with PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: According to the postgresql manual it should run by the `postgres ` user.
Does this command start the postgresql service using the "postgres" user?

Answer (score 28):

From Ubuntu 15.04 onwards do:

```
sudo systemctl enable [SERVICE]
```

Which in your case is:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

Comment: it works, however; after starting ubuntu a popup asks for admin password, anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry, I've been only using a headless ubuntu on a server-system, so I never encountered that issue :-(
Maybe someone else ran into the same problem and can help.

Answer (score 4):

So I figured out how to boot postgresql so i dont need to do the reinstall newb move.

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

you will then need to switch to the postgres user to do any changes within Postgresql

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

I'm sure there are much better answers to this question than mine but this might help someone in my position in the future.

I still need to make Postgresql start on boot. Anyone got the answer to that? Ill gladly mark it as correct.

Cheers

Comment: There is an answer to start automatically upon boot

Answer (score 3):

In the case you don't use the default configuration, like a particular cluster folder, or a custom port, an alternative is to create a `crontab` task that triggers on startup; and configure that task to execute a script that starts the `postgresql` service or whatever you like.

Step 1: switch to the `postgres` user

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Step 2: Use an editor to create the script named "start.sh" in the home folder of the `postgres` user, and fill it with the code that starts the `postgresql` service (or whatever you like). In my case (debian 10, and postgresql 11) the cluster folder ("main") is in a mounted disk ("/mnt/disk"), so the scrip is:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /mnt/disk-b/main -l /var/log/postgresql/pg_ctl.log start
```

Step 3: make said script be executable

```
chmod +x $HOME/start.sh
```

Step 4: create the `crontab` task that triggers on reboots.

```
crontab -e
```

which opens an editor containing the tasks schedule associated to the `postgres` user.

Step 5: Use the opened editor to insert a single line with this content

```
@reboot $HOME/start.sh
```

Step 6: verify the task was added

```
crontab -l
```

Note that the start script is executed using the `postgres` user, which is a requirement according to the `postgresql` manual.

**Edit 1:** If your postgresql installation package includes the command `pg_createcluster`, a better alternative is to use said command to create the cluster, and the `systemctl` command to start the "postgresql" service. This way the service is automatically configured to start at boot.